# R apparently transform accent in coded character UTF-8

Tags: encoding, character, rstudio

when i create on object x with a character string like "Opéra" with accent RStudio returns the object with a codification ( UTF-8 ? ) of the character 
i would like to get "Opéra" instead of this code!
What can i do for this ? is it a problem with my Mac? with
the parameters of R or R Studio ? 
Many thanks for your help .

I am using R version 3.6.1 and RStudio 1.1.456 on a MacBook Pro 
MacOs 10.14.5

x<-"Opéra"
x
[1] "Op\303\251ra"

x<-"Opéra"
x
[1] "Op\303\251ra"

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution to my encoding question : using the package
stringr from R and the command str_replace_all i can easily replace all 
my accents in a variable (column) of a dataset by same characters without accents.
Here is how i proceed with one character then with a vector :
one Character:

```
    x<-"Opéra"
    x
    [1] "Op\303\251ra"
    str_replace(x,"é","e")
    Opera
    #Several Characters in a vector 
    x4<-c("Opéra","Hôtel-de-Ville","Ménilmontant")
    str_replace_all(x4,c("é"="e","ô"="o"))
    [1] "Opera"          "Hotel-de-Ville" "Menilmontant"
```

I can now apply this to an entire column of a dataset 
then create a new column without accents with mutate 
and cancel the old column with those horrible codes like
\303\251 (representing character é)

If you have a more elegant solution i would be very interested
Thanks